# How to change CAB style in Android?

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

I'm trying to change the Contextual Action Bar style using this snippet

```
<style name="AppTheme.Reader" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionMode</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionMode</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionMode" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```

And setting the theme in the right activity

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Reader"
```

Then I've used a

```
TextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback()
```

To intercept the selected text, but when it comes up the CAB it has the default style and seems that my custom hasn't been applied.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest support lib (as of now: v23.4.0). Depends where your parent "AppTheme" inherits from, it may or may not work but if you try to inherit from the "AppCompat" theme the following should work and once you see the white background you can fill in the rest of the attributes:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionModeTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionModeTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Of course assuming `<color name="white">#fff</color>` is defined in `colors.xml`